# How do I create a key-value pair and write it to my badgerDB?

Tags: mapping, key-value, leveldb, badgerdb

Since the new version of `BadgerDB`, many of the old tutorials I've been looking at don't work. So I'm following the documentation, specifically with key loaders: https://godoc.org/github.com/dgraph-io/badger#KVLoader

I've tried making a simple mapping in `Go` but keep getting errors.

My code is simply

```
  db, err := badger.Open(badger.DefaultOptions("./tmp"))
  if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
  }

  defer db.Close()
  // Your code here…

  var env = map[string]int{
     "key0": 10,
     "key1": 398,
  }

  kv := db.NewKVLoader(5)
  kv.Set(env)
```

It keeps saying `cannot use env (type map[string]int) as type *pb.KV in argument to kv.Set`. Should I be using it this way? How can I write my key-value pair?

Comment: wdym write my KV pair? Why cant you use a regular transaction err := db.Update(func(txn *badger.Txn) error {
  err := txn.Set([]byte("answer-key"), []byte("42-value"))
  return err
})

Comment: https://dgraph.io/docs/badger/get-started/#using-key-value-pairs